# AsyncTask load an local file in WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-webview

Before a moderator marks this question as a duplicate, I've read all the related issues in the Stack and had nothing to report on the question!

I'm having problems trying to use AsyncTask with WebView, follow the code

```
    final WebView webNISR = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_NISR);
        final WebSettings webS_NISR = webNISR.getSettings();
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                webNISR.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // I left webNISR.loadUrl here for test, but it keeps processing slow, nothing changes!
                webNISR.loadUrl(getString(R.string.waytofile)+"file.html");
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                webS_NISR.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webS_NISR.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
              //webNISR.loadUrl(params);
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
                webNISR.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };
```

In `doInBackground()` Just do the processing, okay!

But I can not use `webNISR.loadUrl()` inside, I always get the error "**Method loadUrl must be called from the UI or UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker**", but if I am using an AsyncTask for this process to be done on another Thread and do not load UIThread (it's leaving the App slow).

I understand that anything that changes the view must be either `onPostExecute()` or `onPreExecute()`, but would not it be the `webNISR.loadUrl()` that slows the loading of the Activity?

I need the WebView rendering to be "contained" so that I can have porformance gain or just manage to load the page.

It is worth mentioning that per activity there is approximately 7 WebView, so the need to work loading the page.

Note: **WebViews are irreplaceable (only they can load those local files)**

I no longer know what to do, I am days into this battle: /

Any questions are welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`webView.loadUrl()` is asynchronous: it returns immediately and WebView keeps working in it's own thread. So you don't need the `AsyncTask`. I doubt if keeping the `AsyncTask` will add any significant performance gain.

You can set a `WebViewClient` to the `WebView` using `setWebViewClient` and override `onPageFinished` method.
Do what you what when the webview has finished loading inside `onPageFinished` callback.

```
final WebView webNISR = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_NISR);
webNISR.setVisibility(View.GONE);

webNISR.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webNISR.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webNISR.loadUrl(getString(R.string.waytofile)+"file.html");

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webNISR.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: I already tried this method and with or without the same the page stays unstable the same way, I tried to make a controller to make everyone VISIBLE when all were loaded, but for some reason it is impossible access the value of a contained variable In the `onPageFinished()` method.
If you want I'll edit the question and add what I've already tried with this method.